# How do I make menu looks like new Youtube layout

Tags: php, mysql, html, user-interface

I want to know basically how Youtube works between menu & loading the video content.

On http://www.youtube.com/ when we click the menu example Popular, Music, Entertainment and others on right will loading & show videos according to the category we clicked.

When I view the source there is no link to specific `script name`.

```
<li class="guide-item-container">
    <a data-feed-type="system" data-feed-name="popular" class="guide-item">
        <span class="thumb">
          <img alt="" src="//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" class="system-icon system popular">
        </span>
      <span class="display-name">
          Popular
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

May I know how it works.

Comment: There's no need to have a link to a specific script right next to the relevant code. The script can be anywhere in the page. Three's probably an onclick event associated with each specific link and the content is then loaded with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy possibility to find out how youtube loads the contents excatly, but you can see the destination of ajax requests in the network view of you developer tools. The request  on "popular" gets it contents from this url i.e.: [/guide_ajax?action_load_system_feed=1&feed_type=popular](http://www.youtube.com/guide_ajax?action_load_system_feed=1&feed_type=popular) which returns a json.

I'm a little bit wondering that such a major feature like the main navigation has no fallback for users who has disabled javascript, but okay...